# How to validate Integer received from a socket stream in java

Tags: java, sockets, validation

In my application, clients sends file to the server in this format,

```
4 bytes of file length + actual file content
```

So the server reads the first 4 bytes to get the length of message and then it reads upto that message length.

The server code will be like this,

```
ByteArrayOutputStream lengthBuf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(4);
byte[] output = new byte[4];

//Reading first 4 bytes from InputStream
int readLength = inputStream.read(output);
lengthBuf.write(outpu, 0, readLength);

//Converting to integer
int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(lengthBuf.toByteArray()).getInt();
```

It works fine for valid cases. But in case if the client fails to append the length in the first 4 bytes, then this length got some junk value (1481988969). How to validate that the first 4 bytes of data is a valid integer ?

Comment: have u tried output.getInt(); retruns the first four ?

Comment: What if inputStream.read() reads less than 4 bytes?  What happens if the endianness is wrong?

Comment: BTW `Integer` != `int`

Comment: You probably won't believe me but 1481988969 is valid integer

Comment: @talex ist right. How could you know that the file doesn't have a length of 1481988969? You could read the file and check if the size is right. Or you could use a checksum (like CRC) for the int. But this won't always work.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are fixed to 4 bytes and all values of the integer can be valid, there is no way.
However if you can more bytes. You can add a fifth byte and e.g. use CRC or other error-detecting codes to check if the value has correctly been transmitted.

Another option would be if you actually do not need all bits of the four transmitted bytes, that you use some bits of them.

Both actually needs access to the Server-Implementation of the Socket. If you don't have this access, it will not be possible to check if the integer is correct. You only can exclude file sizes which you know that they never occur. E.g.:

```
if (integer < MAX_FILE_SIZE and integer > 0) valid(); 
// or integer >= 0 if empty files are allowed.
else invalid();
```

Comment: This is what I have planned to do at last by comparing with some maximum value. I cannot modify the client code to add additional byte.

Comment: Then i do not see any other chance to check if the received value is correct. Maybe you can send the request twice and check if both results give you the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way.

```
DataInputStream dis  = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
int len = dis.readInt(); // read exactly 4 bytes
byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
dis.readFully(bytes);
```

When you do you first read, you could be getting less than 4 bytes.  When you read the actual data, you might have to read many times to get it all.  `read(byte[])` can return as soon as it get 1 or more bytes.

Comment: How are you saying that I will be getting less than 4 bytes during first read (I mean readInt()) ?. I tried using DataInputStream.readInt() in my case. It returns the random junk value.

Comment: @Prabu I am saying you could read less than 4.  Are the 4 byte `int` value being sent in little or big endian format.  DataInputStream assumes big endian or network format, but most C/C++ program use little endian by default. (Actually this changes depending on the machine it is run on)

Comment: The client is sending 32 bit long big endian (or Network order) and is written in perl using pack("N a*", len, buf);

Comment: @Prabu in that case, this is the correct way to read a 32-bit integer in big-endian byte order. You need to look at what is happening earlier in the stream to work out why the value is corrupt.

Comment: I don't like these pure 'send the size first' protocols. One error in the length data at either end, and the protocol cannot recover.

Answer (score 0):

Why don;t you initalize it with at least size four then , when the client fails to append the size >

```
if(length==null) {

  size = 4 ;

} 
ByteArrayOutputStream lengthBuf = new ByteArrayOutputStream(size);

int length = ByteBuffer.wrap(lengthBuf.toByteArray()).getInt();
```

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you mean here.